# Include a PHP variable in load script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My apologize in advance for my (maybe) stupid question but my knowledge of Javascript/JQuery is almost 0

I have in index.html the following script:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#MyDIV")
   .load("buttons.php") 
  });
</script>
<div id="MyDIV"></div>
```

As you can see, the idea is load **buttons.php** in a div tag in **index.html** - That works fine -

**buttons.php**

```
<div id="buttom">
    <div id="botton5"><a href="#"><img src="5.png" id="5"/></a></div> 
</div>
<script> 
$('#botton5').click(function(event){ 
   $("#bottons").load('somepage.php?answer=5');  //here!

}); 
</script>
```

Thats also **works fine** and I receive the information from somepage.php in MyDIV in index.html

but does not work when I include a php in the URL in the line

```
$("#bottons").load('somepage.php?answer=5&title=<?php echo $title;?>&date=<?php echo $date;?>');   //here!
```

Including a PHP in load, the div does not load in index.html, can you please support me on how to add a php in the URL in load?

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Since you call `somepage.php` from JavaScript you can't use PHP there

Comment: Dom doesn't  support directly  with  php codes

Comment: Did you define `$title` and `$date` before trying to use them?

Comment: Related? One https://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/1809433 Two https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/1809433

Comment: My apologize @NikitaU. but as I said, my knowledge on this is almost 0 and I don't know how to adapt the related post to my situation

Comment: Is this code `$("#bottons").load('somepage.php?answer=5&title=<?php echo $title;?>&date=<?php echo $date;?>');` in your PHP file? If not, it would never work. This JQuery code should be in PHP file.

Comment: @MilanChheda I did not understand your question, but in order to provide more info, all works fine without PHP, even if I change <?php echo $title; ?> and set to <?php echo "Hello World"; ?> does not work

Comment: `somepage.php?answer=5&title=<?php echo $title;?> // does not work`

`somepage.php?answer=5&title=<?php echo "Hello world";?> // does not work`

`somepage.php?answer=5&title=Hello world // Work`

So, I assume that does not work when I include php, but I'm sure that must be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**@Luis Gerardo Runge** In JavaScript you can't use PHP  but logically you can take your value in hidden field and use in javascript. i have add some sample code my be it's help you

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<div id="buttom">
    <div id="botton5"><a href="#"><img src="5.png" id="5"/></a></div> 
</div>
<div id="bottons">

</div>
<?php 
$title = 'your title';
$date = 'yourdate';
?>
<input type="hidden" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo urlencode($title); ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo urlencode($date); ?>">

<script> 
$('#botton5').click(function(event){ 
alert('call');
   $("#bottons").load('json.php?answer=5&title='+$('#title').val()+'&date='+$('#date').val()+'');  //here!

}); 
</script>
```

FYI: You need to use urlencode and urldecode for pass parameter through the URL